# What should I use to control a light on CI Build Failure?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'd like to set up a big light in our office that switches on whenever our Hudson Continuous Integration server reports a build failure. What technology should I use to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Github did something similar with a stop light and their home grown CI Joe build tool (instead of Hudson, but I'd imagine the process is fairly similar).

https://github.com/blog/653-our-new-build-status-indicator

They used an Black Widow Arduino and open-sourced the code to make it work: https://github.com/atduskgreg/GitHub-Stoplight

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Rip your old Thinkpad apart until you get access to the keyboard light.

Step 2) Find an appropriate relay that you can wire in-place of the light (to run your bigger light).

Step 3) Modify the following script to meet your needs (or have it run as-is from whatever checks the builds):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
light_filename = '/proc/acpi/ibm/light'
num_cycles = 1

# see if we have an argument telling how many times to flash
ARGV.each do |a| 
    if a =~ /-c=(\d+)/ 
        num_cycles = $1.to_i 
    else 
        puts 'Unknown argument: ' + a
        exit
    end 
end

# method that reverses the state
def reverse(state)
        return 'on' if state.include? 'off'
        return 'off'
end

# find starting state
state = 'off'
File.open(light_filename, 'r') do |inf| 
    state='on' if inf.gets.include? 'on'
end

# double the cycle num to get how many times we should flip
flips = num_cycles * 2
# do the cycles
flips.times do |i|
    # reverse state
    File.open(light_filename, 'w') do |out| 
        state = reverse(state)
        out.write(state) 
    end
    # wait 1/4 sec before looping again
    sleep 0.250
end
```

(I probably stole that code from somewhere, but it was so long ago now that I can't recall)